# Yahoo Placefinder JSON response in IE

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, api, yahoo

I'm implementing Yahoo Placefinder in my project, via a JSON request. This seems to work fine in Chrome/FF/Safari, however in Internet Explorer (all versions) it tires to download it rather than send a request back.

The standard JSON requset from the Placefinder API seems to have the same issue - `http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=San+Francisco,+CA&flags=J&appid=yourappid`

This is part of the code I'm using in my project.

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
dataType: "json",
cache: false,
url: "http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location="+ address+ ","+ postcode+ "+UK&flags=J&appid=yourappid",.....
```

Why is IE trying to download this file? Any ideas how I can send the request back the same way as the other browsers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When You work with JSON and web services in IE the best practice is that you first encode your request url.
You can do that simple with that java script function:

sampleUrl = **encodeURIComponent**(address+ ","+ postcode+ "+UK&flags=J&appid=yourappid");

and then use **sampleUrl** parameter in call:

$.ajax({

type: "GET",

dataType: "json",

cache: false,

url: "http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=" + sampleUrl

});

Best Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the response! However this encoding seems to ignore the &flags=J parameter (which enables the JSON response) and turn it back into an XML format. Here's the URL generated - 

http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=14a%20wyclioffe%2Cbh9%201jp%2BUK%26flags%3DJ%26appid%3D[appid]%26gflags%3DL&_=1322830795719

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: You must your appid parameter set to the corect value, in your case it is 1322830795719 Here You can see an example: http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?location=San+Francisco,+CA&flags=J&appid=1322830795719 and use encodeURIComponent.